# Taylor vs. Laurent series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

So I'm trying to figure out methods to get a Laurent series instead of a Taylor series. Here is the initial problem:

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)}$$

So if I'm trying to find the Laurent series and I know they need negative exponents, what's the strategy? I know the answer is to factor out a $\frac{1}{z}$ but how would I get there?

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)} = \frac{1}{z} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{z}} = \frac{1}{z}(1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^2} + ... )$$

The above Laurent series (it has negative exponents) converges when $|z| > 1$ right?

And what's the corresponding Taylor series representation? Is the takeaway here that you can represent the same function with two different series?

Comment: Have you seen the construction of the Laurent series on a given annulus? It's probaby better to understand how the proof goes before you do calculations.

Comment: Taylor series doesn't have negative powers of $z$; there is none there

Comment: Can you show me a proof? What do you mean by this @Matematleta?

Comment: @Jwan622 I see you have accepted an answer, but in any case, if you are still interested, [this explanation](https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/18.04/notes/topic7.pdf) might help to clarify the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to have your series centered at $0$, then it turns out that the Laurent series of $\frac1{z-1}$ in $D(0,1)$ is equal to its Taylor series there, which is$$-1-z-z^2-z^3-\cdots$$On the other hand, its Laurent series on $\Bbb C\setminus\overline{D(0,1)}$ is indeed what you got:$$z^{-1}+z^{-2}+z^{-3}+\cdots$$

Comment: What is the d notation?

Comment: @Jwan622 Do you mean $D(0,1)$?

Comment: Yeah what does that notation and what's the bigger picture point you're trying to make? Are you saying there are 2 laurent series?

Comment: The notation $D(z_0,r)$ stands for the open disk $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z-z_0|<r\}$. And, yes, there are two Laurent series, one which converges when $|z|<1$ and another one which converges when $|z|>1$.

Answer (score 0):

We discussed this before, with regards to the function $1/(1-z)$.

You're apparently wondering about uniqueness.  The Laurent (or Taylor) series around a given point can indeed be shown to be unique in a given region.

Comment: Meaning... there's only 1 laurent and 1 taylor series representation of a given function in a given region?

Comment: A Taylor series is a special case of a Laurent series.  There is, in general, only one Laurent series in a given region.  If the Laurent series happens to be a Taylor series, there is still only one.

Comment: and by region you mean centered around a point?

Comment: Well, yes, and then also the region of convergence.  Laurent series typically converge on disks or their complements or annuli, the latter being the intersection of a disk with the complement of a disk.